# How to add measured input values as x-axis labels in generated chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, charts, perfplot

I'm using `perfplot` to make only a few measurements. I would like to see measured input values as x-axis labels similarly to generated y-axis labels.

Currently I see `10^2  10^3  10^4  10^5  10^6  10^7` as x-axis labels.

I want to have `16  512  16384  524288  16777216` as x-axis labels.

`perfplot` uses internally `matplotlib`, so I think it should be possible to achieve.

Example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda a: np.c_[a, a],
        lambda a: np.stack([a, a]).T,
        lambda a: np.vstack([a, a]).T,
        lambda a: np.column_stack([a, a]),
        lambda a: np.concatenate([a[:, None], a[:, None]], axis=1),
    ],
    labels=["c_", "stack", "vstack", "column_stack", "concat"],
    n_range=[16, 512, 16384, 524288, 16777216],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
```

Current output:

[image]

Comment: I don't follow your question. What kind x-labels do you want to see?

Comment: @PaulH I just edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: you should look into existing questions around matplotlib's axis Locators and 
Formatters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `plot` instead of `show` to get access to the current axes object after `perfplot` has finished and then set ticks as needed:

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mt

n_range = [16, 512, 16384, 524288, 16777216]

perfplot.plot(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda a: np.c_[a, a],
        lambda a: np.stack([a, a]).T,
        lambda a: np.vstack([a, a]).T,
        lambda a: np.column_stack([a, a]),
        lambda a: np.concatenate([a[:, None], a[:, None]], axis=1),
    ],
    labels=["c_", "stack", "vstack", "column_stack", "concat"],
    n_range=n_range,
    xlabel="len(a)",
)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(n_range)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mt.StrMethodFormatter('{x}'))
plt.show()
```

[image]